# How do I make a cell highlighted if the date in the cell is today?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advanced date logic in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/advanced-date-logic-in-google-spreadsheets)

I have a spreadsheet with many consecutive days. So Cell1 = `7/30/2012`, Cell2 = `7/31/2012` etc. I want Cell1 to be highlighted if today is 7/30/2012 and Cell2 to be highlighted if today is 7/31/2012.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/advanced-date-logic-in-google-spreadsheets), you'll want to use [conditional formatting](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78413).

1. Select the cells and select Format > Conditional Formatting
2. Select `"Date is"` `"today"` and select a `Background` colour

Comment: If your answer points to another question on the site you should really be flagging as a duplicate.