# Date Formatting for Deadlines

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have set up a Google spreadsheet for managing projects and due dates, and I need to apply the following formatting to a column of dates, but I'm not sure how:

- Dates more than 7 days from today: Black
- Dates less than or equal to 7 days from today: Green
- Dates before today (late projects): Red

[I found someone having a similar issue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/advanced-date-logic-in-google-spreadsheets), but this doesn't actually do what it needs to do. It turns dates that are only 1 week LATE orange. It does not change dates that are one week AWAY orange. So this isn't working... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

For `Dates more than 7 days from today: Black` I am assuming (i) more than 7 days *in advance of* today and (ii) black *font* is suitable – so no conditional formatting is necessary other than that applied elsewhere.

For `Dates less than or equal to 7 days from today: Green` I am again assuming in advance of and suggest select column, Format, Conditional formatting…, Custom formula is:

```
=and(A1<today()+7,A1>=today())
```

with Background Colour: ticked and green chosen.

For `Dates before today (late projects): Red` select column, Format, Conditional formatting…, Custom formula is: as before and:

```
=and(A1<>"",A1<today())
```

with Background Colour: ticked and red chosen.